# How to remove border radius when use Highcharts renderer.rect function

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

How can I remove border radius for rendered.rect method.
I tried to add css method use this but not success.

```
.css({
   borderRadius: 'none'
})
```

Here is my code.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
            type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        max: 300
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

}, function (chart) {
  let maxPoint = chart.series[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a.y > b.y ? a : b);
    for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    var point = chart.series[0].data[i];
        let text = chart.renderer.text(
            'Hien' + i,
            point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 10,
            maxPoint.plotY + chart.plotTop - 10
        ).attr({
            zIndex: 5
        }).add();
        let box = text.getBBox();

    chart.renderer.rect(point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 5, maxPoint.plotY + chart.plotTop - 25, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5)
        .attr({
            fill: '#FFFFEF',
            stroke: 'gray',
            'stroke-width': 1,
            zIndex: 4
        }).css({
         borderRadius: 'none'
        })
        .add();
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px; width: 400"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `.rect()` is:

> rect( [x] [, y] [, width] [, height] [, r] [, strokeWidth])

The fifth parameter is border corner radius so you just need to set it to 0.

```
chart.renderer.rect(
  point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 5, 
  maxPoint.plotY + chart.plotTop - 25, 
  box.width + 10, 
  box.height + 10, 
  0
)...
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
            type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        max: 300
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

}, function (chart) {
  let maxPoint = chart.series[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a.y > b.y ? a : b);
    for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    var point = chart.series[0].data[i];
        let text = chart.renderer.text(
            'Hien' + i,
            point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 10,
            maxPoint.plotY + chart.plotTop - 10
        ).attr({
            zIndex: 5
        }).add();
        let box = text.getBBox();

    chart.renderer.rect(point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 5, maxPoint.plotY + chart.plotTop - 25, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 0)
        .attr({
            fill: '#FFFFEF',
            stroke: 'gray',
            'stroke-width': 1,
            zIndex: 4
        })
        .add();
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px; width: 400"></div>
```